# Hide a specific part of an iframe

Tags: html, iframe

So I have an iframe based clock on my website that has the time and am/pm. However I find the am/pm to look bad, is there any way I can remove the am/pm. (I dont have access to the website that the iframe points to)

I have tried adjusting the width, but when the time changes the numbers get wider and the it numbers get hidden. ty :)